# Dependent Dropdown box (Form Control) Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a dependent dropdown box which is dependent on selection of a "parent" DropDown box. All placed in a sheet. But it seems to fail.
Error, Expected Function or Variable .. 
Here's the code;

```
Sub DropDown112_Change()
Dim index As Integer
index = DropDown112.ListIndex

DropDown56.Clear
Case Is = 0
   With DropDown56
    .AddItem "Yes"
    .AddItem "No"

End With

Case Is = 1
   With DropDown56
   .AddItem "Maybe"

 End With
 End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no `Select Case...` statement to kick off the cases

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying what's being switched on.

```
Case Is = 0
```

What is `Is`? You're missing a `Select Case {expression}` statement/block:

```
Select Case foo
    Case 0
        'foo is 0
    Case 1
        'foo is 1
End Select
```

Note that `Is =` is redundant.

---

As for the "object required" error, that's because you're not specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and thus allow your code to be executed without compile-time validation of your identifiers.

```
DropDown56.Clear
```

If `DropDown56` doesn't exist, then without `Option Explicit` that `DropDown56` identifier becomes a `Variant/Empty` at run-time, and `Variant/Empty` doesn't have a `.Clear` member, because it's not an object - hence "object required".

Make sure all your dropdown identifiers refer to actual control names that exist. `Option Explicit` will validate that and prevent successfully compiling & running code that has typos in variable names. **Always. Use. Option. Explicit.**

Comment: No I have added " "Select Case Dropdown1.ListIndex"" But instead I gott error "Run time error 424, Object required"

Comment: @Martinswe great! that should fix the compile error... assuming you also added `End Select` at the end of the cases.

Comment: @Martinswe not sure which statement raises that error, but I'm putting my money on `DropdownXYZ` controls not existing. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, then try to compile your code (from the "Debug" menu); if a control doesn't exist, VBA understands it as an undeclared object variable. Without `Option Explicit`, you allow the code to run like this, with undeclared variables. Rename your controls so that they have meaningful names, so that you can tell at a glance whether `FooBox` exists on your sheet/form or not.

Comment: Thanks for you help!! Now there's is that other probelm ,"object variable or with block variable not set" which seems to be part; "index = Dropdown1.ListIndex"...

Comment: You would get that error if you declared a `Dropdown1` variable and used it without assigning it a reference. If you mean to work with named controls, verify that they exist at  design/compile-time- then you don't need a variable for them (assuming ActiveX/MSForms controls). If you mean to *retrieve* controls at runtime, you need to declare a variable for it, and then `Set` it to a valid object reference before you can use it. That said we're getting pretty far from the originally asked question now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to deal with cascading drop downs, I always set a range on a separate sheet.  That way I can resize and administer the options and sub-options without going back into the code.  I made a quick example below:

[image: Cascading DDs]

Code:

```
Private Sub cmbContinents_Change()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim countries() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Me.cmbCountries.Clear
    i = 0
    ReDim countries(i)

    For Each rng In Range("ddCountries")
        If UBound(Filter(countries, rng.Value)) = -1 And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = Me.cmbContinents.Value Then
            ReDim Preserve countries(i)
            countries(i) = rng.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next rng

    For j = 0 To UBound(countries)
        Me.cmbCountries.AddItem (countries(j))
    Next j
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim continents() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Me.cmbContinents.Clear
    i = 0
    ReDim continents(i)

    For Each rng In Range("ddContinents")
        If UBound(Filter(continents, rng.Value)) = -1 Then
            ReDim Preserve continents(i)
            continents(i) = rng.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next rng

    For j = 0 To UBound(continents)
        Me.cmbContinents.AddItem (continents(j))
    Next j
End Sub
```

The way this works is by setting the values of the Continents drop down (cmbContinents) at the moment the worksheet is activated.  The Countries (cmbCountries) aren't populated until you make a selection in the Continent section.  This might not be the most efficient way (I'm sure others have more efficient code) but this will at least mean you won't have to hard-code the options.

The code is housed within the Worksheet but could easily be functioned off into a module.